# java.io.FileNotFoundException: \opt\tomcatd\tempfiles\

Tags: java, ios, file-upload, file-io

Java is not picking up the correct directory for uploading the file. I am uploading the file from desktop. This is the code I am using to pick up the drive, and file_drive returns "\opt\tomcatd\tempfiles\", which is not correct.

```
file_drive = glb.getSysProps().getProperty("FILE_DRIVE");
```

Any suggestions on how to go about this issue?

Comment: Please more details on the context in which this code runs.  What Java platform?  Release?  What libraries?  What application?  And ... why do your pathnames have backslash as the pathname separator?

Comment: @StephenC glb.getSysProps().getProperty("FILE_DRIVE") is returning the pathname, which apparently is not returning the correct one.

Comment: How about responding to the rest of questions that I asked?  'Cos if you don't, I doubt that anyone can help you.